# Implementing Jquery ajax get request in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Am more of an angular person so i do not really do well with jquery. I have a project i took over from someone and i have to implement a get request to my controller and append returned data to view. I know this is vague but i would appreciate any help.

```
<tbody>
        @foreach($restaurant_meals as $meal)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{$meal->name}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    ${{$meal->price}}
                </td>

                <td>
                    <a href=""><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
```

This is my view. 
This is my ajax request.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(documnent).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
        url: '/addtocartid' + id, // This is the url we gave in the route
        data: {'id' : id}, // a JSON object to send back
        success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
            console.log(response); 
        }
    });
});
```

Then my Controller would be

```
public function getaddtoCart(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')  : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);
    $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Yeah I have no idea what is your question/problem.

Comment: I think the `url` might not look good since if `id` is simply a integer, it'll generate something like `/addtocartid2` instead of `/addtocartid/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the concatenation of the `id` in the URL. It is adding the extra numbers in the URL pattern.

```
$(documnent).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET', // Type of response and matches what we said in the route
        url: '/addtocartid', // This is the url we gave in the route
        data: {'id' : id}, // a JSON object to send back
        success: function(response){ // What to do if we succeed
            console.log(response); 
        }
    });
});
```

Like `/addtocartid1` instead of `/addtocartid/1`

Ideally that should be removed. You are already sending the parameters by `data` property